# How to add a remote postgres database in my django app?

Tags: django, postgresql

What I'am trying to do is to use 2 databases in my django app. One is to be accessed from a remote server.  Django settings has something like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'snackvoxadmin'
    },
    'users': {
        .....
    }


}
```

The database user has a url like similar to this one: postgres://a78adj1he81....

Answer (score 11):

You can decompose your database url and configure it like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

And the pattern for a database url is :

```
postgres://user:password@host:post/database
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

---

Or you can use the package [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) to directly use the database url.

E.g. from readme :

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse('postgres://...')}
```

Comment: Cool! Now I just have to work on the relations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was using the same with heroku and now i moved to pythonanywhere are postrgres db from neon, though the things work fine locally, app connects with the remote db but on pythonanywhere, it fails. It gives a connection error,

Answer (score 1):

That URL presumably consists of a username, a password, and a host name/IP address. You could split them up yourself or use the dj-database-url library.